# Get unread mails in lotus notes using vbscript

Tags: vbscript, lotus-notes, lotus

How to get all unread mails from a particular view(eg $Inbox) of lotus notes database using vbscript?

```
    Set objNotesSession = CreateObject("Lotus.NotesSession")
    objNotesSession.Initialize(strPassword)
    Set objNotesdb = objNotesSession.GETDATABASE(strMailServer, 
                       strMailDBName) 
    If Not objNotesdb.IsOpen = True Then 
        Call objNotesdb.Open 
    End If
    Dim view
    Dim vec
    Set view = objNotesdb.GetView("($Drafts)")
    vec = view.GetAllUnreadEntries()
```

But for GetAllUnreadEntries() I am getting Object doesn't support this property or method

Comment: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSVRGU_8.5.3/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_ACCESSING_THE_DOMINO_OBJECTS_THROUGH_COM.html

Answer (score 1):

You can get all unread documents from the Inbox by using the [GetAllUnreadEntries method](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSVRGU_8.5.3/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_GETALLUNREADENTRIES.html) in the [NotesView class](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSVRGU_8.5.3/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_NOTESVIEW_CLASS.html). The result will be returned as a [NotesViewEntryCollection object.](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSVRGU_8.5.3/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_NOTESVIEWENTRYCOLLECTION_9327.html)

Comment: It is EXACTLY the same in vbscript as in LotusScript.

Comment: The links I provided cover classes that work for LotusScript, COM, and OLE. You should probably be using COM from VBScript, but you might be using OLE. Most of the time, the documentation is good about calling out the differences between LotusScript and COM. It is not always as good about calling out the differences with OLE. The best way to address your concern would be to revise your question by posting the code you have tried, and then adding comments here telling us exactly what happens when you try and call GetAllUnreadEntries.

Comment: for GetAllUnreadEntries() I am getting Object doesn't support this property or method

Comment: Okay. You're using COM, not OLE. Unfortunately, the version of Notes that you have installed appears to not support the GetAllUnreadEntries method in the COM classes. What version are you working with?

Comment: Version that I am using is Notes 9.0

Comment: Then I'm afraid there is no easy solution to your problem from vbscript. You would have to find a way for your script to run a LotusScript agent on the Domino server and then retrieve the results from there, or you would have to find a way to make calls to the Notes C or C++ API from.